# How to create Google Contact using Google API

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am trying to create Google Contact using `Google Contacts API`.
According to Google doc(as below), I have already implement the create function.

[Google Docs Creating contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts)

To create a new contact, send an authorized `POST` request to the user's contacts feed URL with contact data in the body.
The URL is of the form:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```

I use this query to create a contact:

```
  www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```

However, the new contact is created in the group `"Other Contact"` by default.

How can I directly create in the group `"My Contact"`?

Do I need to modify the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#authorizing_requests_to_the_api_name_service):

> Contact Group Entry
>
> Contacts can be placed into user-defined groups. You can create,
>   retrieve, update, and delete these groups using the Contacts Data API,
>   and you can add contacts to a group or remove contacts from a group.
>   For details, see the following sections.
>
> The Contacts Data API also provides access to four predefined "system
>   groups" for each user:
>
> My Contacts Friends Family Coworkers System groups appear in a groups
>   feed just like user-defined groups do. In fact, system groups are
>   mostly treated just like other groups. The differences are:
>
> Each system group entry contains a  subelement.
>   The id attribute of that subelement indicates which system group the
>   group is: Contacts, Friends, Family, or  Coworkers. Note that the My
>   Contacts ID value is simply  Contacts, without the "My". Also note
>   that this system group ID value is different from the group ID given
>   in the group entry's   element. You can't add new system groups,
>   change the name of a system group, add extended properties to a system
>   group, or delete a system group. * The contact-group entry
>   representing a system group doesn't contain a rel="edit" link.

Comment: I did down voted this answer because I could mot find the actual answer.

Comment: "My Contacts" is a predefined 'system group'. You need to add the contact to that group. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#changing_group_membership

Comment: finally got around to writing a blog post how exactly how to do this: https://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2018/01/create-google-contact-api-my-contacts-system-group.html

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_group_id(label_name):
    feed = gd_client.GetGroups()
    for entry in feed.entry:
        if entry.title.text.lower() == label_name:
            return entry.id.text


contact_entry = gdata.contacts.data.ContactEntry() #contact_entry
group = get_group_id("My Contact") #group id
membership = gdata.contacts.data.GroupMembershipInfo(href=group) #group membership
contact_entry.group_membership_info.append(membership) # adding group membership to   contact_entry
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not true that contacts can only be placed into user-defined groups. I just experimented with Google Contact V3 API and was able to put a contact under system defined group (My contacts):

```
ContactEntry contact = new ContactEntry();
Name name = new Name();
final String NO_YOMI = null;
name.setFullName(new FullName("Elizabeth Bennet", NO_YOMI));
name.setGivenName(new GivenName("Elizabeth", NO_YOMI));
name.setFamilyName(new FamilyName("Bennet", NO_YOMI));
contact.setName(name);

GroupMembershipInfo groupInfo = new GroupMembershipInfo();
//You can fetch the following link from GroupEntry#getId()  
groupInfo.setHref("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{EmailId}/base/{groupId}");
groupInfo.setDeleted(false);
contact.getGroupMembershipInfos().add(groupInfo);
ContactEntry createdContact = myService.insert(new URL(
    "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{EmailId}/full"), contact);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pl note that Google Contacts API has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/people/contacts-api-migration) since Jan 2022 and you need to use [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts)